# libboost-all-dev didn't generate the '-mt' libraries

Tags: boost

I have installed the `libboost-all-dev` package, and cannot find the thread aware libraries I need inside my `/usr/lib/` directory. (libboost_system-mt.a)

Are the library files that aren't suffixed with `-mt` thread aware? (As none of them are suffixed)