# Cannot find boost-thread-mt library

Tags: c++, boost

I am compiling a program which requires boost-thread-mt library. I have installed libboost-all-dev using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` but compiler says that it cannot find boost-thread-mt library. Is this library in some other package? Please guide me what i need to install for this.

Comment: Do you have `libboost-thread-dev` installed?

Comment: There are no `-mt` libraries in the main Boost package. See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362612/libboost-all-dev-didnt-generate-the-mt-libraries?rq=1) unresolved question.

Comment: How can I install -mt libraries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-mt` suffix had been removed. The installed Boost libraries are multi-threading safe.

You can compile your program versus `libboost-thread`. Either by changing the source to use non `-mt` libs or by making symbolic links `libboost_thread.a` →`libboost_thread-mt.a`. Same thing if you need shared libs `.so`.

Comment: So... any advice on doing cross-platform development given that Ubuntu in its wisdom decided to do things differently from everyone else?

Comment: @Pseudonym, if you are using GNU autotools, see [Autotconf: `AC_CHECK_LIB`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Libraries)

Comment: Autoconf is overkill for many projects, especially if you're using Boost.Build.

Comment: @Pseudonym, I'm not so familiar with boost but [`check-target-builds`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/bbv2/reference.html#bbv2.reference.rules)  seems to offer same functionality of autoconf for boost.build.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293962/boost-libraries-in-multithreading-aware-mode) is related to this question.

You may as well try compiling boost from source rather than using the apt-get version.

The arguments `--layout`, `threading` and `build-type` will help.

```
--layout=<layout>     Determines whether to choose library names
                      and header locations such that multiple
                      versions of Boost or multiple compilers can
                      be used on the same system.

                      versioned - Names of boost binaries
                      include the Boost version number, name and
                      version of the compiler and encoded build
                      properties.  Boost headers are installed in a
                      subdirectory of <HDRDIR> whose name contains
                      the Boost version number.

                      tagged -- Names of boost binaries include the
                      encoded build properties such as variant and
                      threading, but do not including compiler name
                      and version, or Boost version. This option is
                      useful if you build several variants of Boost,
                      using the same compiler.

                      system - Binaries names do not include the
                      Boost version number or the name and version
                      number of the compiler.  Boost headers are
                      installed directly into <HDRDIR>.  This option
                      is intended for system integrators who are
                      building distribution packages.

                  The default value is 'versioned' on Windows, and
                  'system' on Unix.
```

So, try this command to install boost, after `bootstrap.sh --prefix=/path/of/yours`:

```
./b2 install -j16 threading=multi --layout=tagged --build-type=complete
```

Then you'll get all the `-mt` libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses `CMake`, this following switch provided in [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html) module has to turned off: `-DBoost_USE_MULTITHREADED=OFF`