# Cannot find "-lboost_python-mt" error when using Boost

Tags: boost

I am trying to build PyVlfeat and it is failing with the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py34
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

I have seen threads mentioning similar issue, but none of those seem to provide a proper solution and they seem to be quite old.

The issue here is that the installation script refers to "-lboost_python-mt-py26" option (parameter?) at one point. Some threads seem to reach a solution by changing their python interpreter version. (eg: py27 instead of py26).

However this doesn't work for me and I am unable to correct this reference. I have installed Boost by the command "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev".

How to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find boost-thread-mt library](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486006/cannot-find-boost-thread-mt-library)

Comment: As per the answer mentioned there, I have changed my reference to "-lboost_python-py27" and this time it seems to have compiled successfully. Thanks. However, I had python 2.7 and 3.4 in my system. How to find the proper boost libraries in my system so that I can use the correct one? If somebody can explain this in an answer, it will be very useful as I don't think much information regarding this is available in net.

Comment: It depends on which Python version you are using: for python2 use `-lboost_python-py27`, for python3 use `-lboost_python-py34`. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned, changing the reference to "-lboost_python-py27" helps to solve the problem.

The source of the information is
[Cannot find boost-thread-mt library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486006/cannot-find-boost-thread-mt-library)